# C++ how to input by word and count how much word i input

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while, goto

i did try using this program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    string a = "black";
    string b = "red";
    string c = "white";

    int e, f, g = 0; //e = black; f = red; h = white;

    cout << "input car color :";
    cin >> x;
    if (x == a) {
        cout << "continue input car color?" << endl;
    }
    else if (x == b) {
        cout << "continue input car color?" << endl;
    }




        return 0;
}
```

but i dont know to make the last one that show how much color did user input

this is the result for my program, how do i make it? and its in c++ btw

```
input car color: black                //black,red,white=user input
continue input car color? (y/n)? y
input car color: black
continue input car color? (y/n)? y
input car color: black
continue input car color? (y/n)? y
input car color: red
continue input car color? (y/n)? y
input car color: white
continue input car color? (y/n)? n

detail car color
black      3 car
red        1 car
white      1 car
```

Comment: you tagged `loops`. Do you know how a loop works?

Comment: isn't for looping the questiob input car color> or is it goto , while, for?

Comment: Don't use `goto`.  Use a `for` loop when you know ahead of time how many iterations to run. Use a `while` loop when you don't know how many iterations to run. Though, a `do..while` loop would be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: `goto` is hard to get right. It is harder to get right and get easy-to-read and easy-to-maintain code. It is even harder still to convince everyone else who needs to work with your code that `goto` was the correct choice. I've found that using `goto` dooms you to having to continually defend using `goto`, and that quickly soaks up more time than writing the code without `goto` or rewriting the code to not use `goto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop to continue prompting the user for more inputs.  And you need to increment your integers on each matching input you detect.

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    int num_black = 0, num_red = 0, num_white = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "input car color :";
        cin >> input;

        if (input == "black") {
            ++num_black;
        }
        else if (input == "red") {
            ++num_red;
        }
        else if (input == "white") {
            ++num_white;
        }

        cout << "continue input car color?" << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
    while (input == "y");

    cout << endl;
    cout << "detail car color" << endl;
    cout << setw(11) << left << "black" << num_black << " car" << (num_black != 1 ? "s" : "") << endl;
    cout << setw(11) << left << "red" << num_red << " car" << (num_red != 1 ? "s" : "") << endl;
    cout << setw(11) << left << "white" << num_white << " car" << (num_white != 1 ? "s" : "") << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/yJbD8H)

Answer (score -3):

[Below](https://onlinegdb.com/5plGMvI44) is a working example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>//needed for formatting
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    string black_string = "black";
    string red_string = "red";
    string white_string = "white";

    int count_black = 0, count_red =0, count_white = 0; //e = black; f = red; g = white;

    std::string yes_or_no;
    
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "input car color :";
        cin >> x;
    
        if (x == black_string) 
        {
            ++count_black;
            cout << "continue input car color(y/n)?";
            std::cin >> yes_or_no;
            if(yes_or_no == "n")
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (x == red_string) 
        {
            ++count_red;
            cout << "continue input car color?(y/n)";
            std::cin>>yes_or_no;
            if(yes_or_no == "n")
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (x == white_string) 
        {
            ++count_white;
            cout << "continue input car color?(y/n)" ;
            std::cin>>yes_or_no;
            if(yes_or_no == "n")
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "detail car color" << endl;
    std::cout<<std::setw(11) << left <<"black: "<<count_black<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::setw(11) << left <<"red: "<< count_red<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::setw(11) << left <<"white: "<<count_white<<std::endl;


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: A comment like the one used here `int e = 0, f =0, g = 0; //e = black; f = red; g = white;` is an admission that your variable naming is insufficient. Prefer to use descriptive identifiers so that readers of the code don't have to go looking for explanatory comments. Good code comments itself.

Comment: Ofcourse you can change the variable name as much you like but that is not the point of what the OP asked. I just added the needed functionality. Learn to understand the difference between what is needed and what is not that is what is asked in the question.